# Retrieve the position of a content control inside a word document

Tags: ms-word, vsto, word-contentcontrol

Is it possible in VSTO to get the *position* (that is the page number or the section/chapter) where a content control is placed ?
Eg. I would like to retrieve that the ctrl Req234 is on chap. 4.1 (headings) or on page xy

```
4. Title Lorem ipsum
 4.1 Subtitle 
 Lorem ipsum 
 [Req234]
5. Title
```

The control could be surrounded by a Bookmark if it is easier to retrieve bookmark position.

Answer (score 2):

Find that the Range has this method to achieve my task

contentcontrol.Range.get_Information(WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber);

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213848(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I have literally searched for hours for this info! I needed wdEndOfRangeColumnNumber and wdEndOfRangeRowNumber to retrieve an element's position in a table. Thanks!